# Chemdoodle to mestranova

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, software

Is it possible to copy my chemdoodle displayed structure into mestranovea? I have tried simple dragging (mac) and all the various copy/paste options... any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ChemDoodle contains many options for communicating chemical data to other applications. The most common way is to use the Edit>Copy as... function and choose a chemical type to be put on the system clipboard as a string.

If you use the copy function in ChemDoodle, a wide range of common data types, from chemical to image, are placed on the system clipboard for a 3rd party application to paste. You can control what is placed on the clipboard in ChemDoodle's advanced preferences.

ChemDoodle also supports round trip editing with applications that will allow it. However, if none of this works with the application you are pasting into, you will have to contact that specific vendor.

More information on working with ChemDoodle data in 3rd party applications can be found in Chapter 11 of the ChemDoodle User Guide: http://www.chemdoodle.com/downloads/UserGuide.pdf

For further help, please open a ticket here: https://support.ichemlabs.com